# CSS Minifier in PHP

Tags: php, css

Do you know a small but effective class for minifying CSS files written in php that has no extra requirements? It shall serve to optimize user generated files and has to support CSS3 including the vendor specific hacks and fallbacks for older browser (-moz- & -webkit- not being seen as comments).

I have searched for this topic a little bit but it seems like most solutions here are more or less outdated :(

Comment: It's called ["HTTP compression"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good experience with [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/). You can rip out the [CSS compressor class](http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/trunk/min/lib/Minify/CSS/Compressor.php). Should work with something like:

```
$minified = Minify_CSS_Compressor::process($css);
```

Comment: thx! :D
With this version the website looks the same (wont break CSS3 including hacks to provide fallbacks for IE...)

In comparision to the output of the outdated CSStidy it takes a little more space but that might be caused by keeping all data ;)

Answer (score 2):

[CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) - It has a PHP and C++ implementation.

The following is a basic example how to use CSSTidy in PHP:

```
<?php
include('class.csstidy.php');

$css_code = '
a {
  color:black;
  background-color:blue;
}';

$css = new csstidy();

$css->set_cfg('remove_last_;',TRUE);

$css->parse($css_code);

echo $css->print->formatted();

?>
```

Comment: Sorry but csstidy is sadly far outdated or something like this.
at least I got a full page of errors and after them it send some css code that looks a little bit optimized. Lets see if it broke or it still works
I tried with some sample file from wordpress twenty eleven theme as it uses CSS3 a lot (and csstidy's last build is more than 4 years old!)

Comment: @user850533: To which CSS3 standard are you referring to?